# Virtual environment is not recognized as an internal or external command in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I am trying to run code on vscode and I have a folder, workplse, and a file inside it called please.py, i coded in vscode to make a virtual environment called venv, but when I try to activate it I am given
'venv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Here is my folder
[image: error pic]

The command and error code is here:
[image: thing]

Comment: Show us the exact command and output (as copied code-formatted text)!

Comment: I have added it @KlausD.

Comment: You're using forward slashes in your command, but on Windows you need backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

It should be an absolute path while not a relative path, such as:

```
c:/Work/python3.10/.venv/Scripts/activate.bat
```

And you needn't activate the virtual environment manually, through the shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`** to create a new terminal, the Python extension will activate the python environment which you have selected automatically.